# Should I use array or string in link param in CakePHP HtmlHelper?

Tags: php, cakephp, html-helper

CakePHP HtmlHelper `link()` method accepts 2 types of variable as second parameter (the link URL param).

Now I wonder if using array for the param, like

> `array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login')`

is slower than using string, like `'/users/login'`. Because Helper won't have to parse the array, just display the link.

If it is so, then what is the purpose of `link()` method? For now, I am using `HtmlHelper::url()` method with a regular `<a>` to display all of my links, to keep my template clean!

Please correct me :)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I've found a similiar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233259/is-this-overkill-or-good-use-of-cakephps-html-helper), and decided to use Helpers for links and images, as I did before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason is reverse routing: For examples, if you route '/blah' to array('controller'=>'articles','action'=>'index'). When you create the link with array('controller'=>'articles','action'=>'index'), cake can automatically output '/blah'. It may not sound very interesting; but if later on you change the route to '/foo', then the link() method can automatically change the output to '/foo'.

Another reason is: using array you can build the url in a programmatic fashion. It's not just controller and action, you also have prefix, named parameters, your own custom parameters if you create in routes, etc.

`For now, I am using HtmlHelper::url() method with a regular <a> to display all of my links, to keep my template clean!` Well, you are making it harder on yourself then :)

Answer (score 2):

This provides a consistent and flexible method for creating hyperlinks, referencing controllers / actions and specifying dynamic `options` via associative arrays. Performance shouldn't be an issue unless you are iteratively creating links. Even then, array management and implosion is usually much more efficient than string concatenation.